# AttributeError at /posts/create/ : 'str' object has no attribute 'set' when trying to parse hashtags from title field and save it in tags field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to parse hashtags from title field and save to tags field with a `post_save signal` in django. I am using `django-taggit` package for tags but getting this error while saving the `form.save_m2m`. Can someone help to solve this error?

```
this is the link to the package: https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html
```

signal.py

```
def parse_hash_tags(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    post_save.disconnect(parse_hash_tags, sender=Post)
    instance.tags = ','.join(re.findall(r'(?:#(\w+))', instance.title))
    instance.save()
    post_save.connect(parse_hash_tags, sender=Post)

post_save.connect(parse_hash_tags, sender=Post)
```

traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py" in dispatch
  52.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\danny\Study\test\posts\views.py" in post
  231.          form.save_m2m()

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _save_m2m
  441.                 f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])

File "C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\taggit\managers.py" in save_form_data
  517.         getattr(instance, self.name).set(*value)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /posts/create/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'
```

Comment: You can not set a comma separated string as a list of tags.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am quite new to this. so can you tell me what change I can make here to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use a comma separated list as value for a many-to-many relation. You can however make a list of tags, and then use the [**`.set(…)`** method [readthedocs]](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.set):

```
def parse_hash_tags(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    tags = re.findall(r'(?:#(\w+))', instance.title)
    instance.tags.set(*tags)

post_save.connect(parse_hash_tags, sender=Post)
```

Setting a many-to-many relation does not trigger saving the instance itself, so there is no need to call `instance.save()` either and disconnecting/reconnecting. Disconnecting is also a bit "tricky" since another model object that is modified concurrently could then no longer trigger the signal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the new information, but I tried the code, it isn't saving the hashtags to tags field after saving the form as I am expecting it to be..

Comment: @Danny: but you are not triggering `form.save()`, or `form.save_m2m()` right? Since then you will "undo" the work of course done by the trigger. It might however be better to move the logic to the form I guess, and not use a signal anyway.

Comment: Oh. okay! so did you mean to do it before the form gets saved in views or at the front end?

Comment: @Danny: if you use `instance = form.save(commit=False)`, then `instance.save()` you will avoid the `form.save_m2m()`. But perhaps it is better to '*drop*" the signal, and implement it in the `form.save_m2m()` since that will make it a lot more convenient.

Comment: Okay, I got you. Thanks a lot. I will try it.